# Should I use EventHandler<T> and/or the EventArgs delegate pattern?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

Reading my C# book, it talks about using events/delegates (I am assuming I am right in thinking an event is the equivalent of a public delegate which has no member variable access) in a pattern liked by MS:

```
public delegate Something(object o, EventArgs e)
```

And then goes onto explain about `EventArgs<T>` which basically removes the need for the delegate declaration:

```
public EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> events
```

Which is the same as (I think)

```
private delegate Something(object o, SomeEventArgs e);

public event Something events;
```

Is it a good idea to use `EventHandler`? I can see why sending the `object` could be useful, but not all the time - and a lot of the time, the EventArgs may just become annoying to deal with.

Comment: Personally I am not a fan of the event handler pattern in its current form. In fact your last sentence sums up my reasons quite nicely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft has definitely pushed some great patterns that has made working with C# a pleasant experience. That being said, I recommend you write your event handlers to be convenient for your client code rather than writing a lot of code just to meet a pattern.

```
delegate void ClientMessageHandler(IClient client, IMessage message);
```

Comment: Isn't this almost exactly the same as my 3rd code part, except with IClient instead of object and IMessage instead of EventArgs? If so, I don't see what I gain from this except having to make sure I implement IClient and IMessage...knowing me, I'm missing something big ;-)

Comment: @The Communist Duck - The difference is that you are never quite sure what `sender` is without checking the documentation. The event raiser also has to initialize an `EventArgs` object just to wrap the `IMessage` instance. This delegate signature speaks for itself.

Comment: See also the following for another approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809609/c-sharp-simple-event-raising-using-sender-vs-custom-eventargs